# Using MEF with abstract base class

Tags: c#, mef, composition

I'm building a database import app than I want to be extensible (custom db models can be added as needed).  My base component has methods that extended types have to implement: MapData & SaveData.

I defined the base as an abstract class, and everything works when the extended types are in the same namespace.  However, I want to use MEF to import extended types in a different namespace at runtime, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Base class:

```
namespace Program
{
   public abstract class Component
   {
      public abstract string TypeName { get; }
      public abstract DataSet MapData( DataSet db );
      public abstract bool SaveData();
   }
}
```

Extended class (in a separate project):

```
using Program.Component;
namespace ExtendedType
{
   [Export( typeof( Component )]
   class Type1 : Component
   {
       public override string TypeName { get { return "Type1" } }
       public override DataSet MapData( DataSet db )
       {
          // create various object models from db here 
          return db;
       }
       public override bool SaveData()
       {
          // save object models 
          return true;
       }
   }
}
```

Program to import all extended types:

```
namespace Program
{
   [ImportMany( typeof( Component ) )]
   public IEnumerable<Component> componentTypes;

   public Program()
   {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add( new AssemblyCatalog( typeof( Component ).Assembly ) );
        container = new CompositionContainer( catalog );
        this.container.ComposeParts( this );
   }
}
```

According to what I've read, the [ImportMany] attribute on IEnumerable should fill that at runtime but it's always empty. The CompositionContainer is always empty as well.

What did I set up incorrectly?  How can I get a list of the extended Component types?

Comment: Links that I've found are similar to what I'm want to do: 

Extend types in the same namespace: [link](http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/abstract-class-with-mef/)

Export/ImportMany types in different namespaces: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188054/An-Introduction-to-Managed-Extensibility-Framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating an Extensions directory for the MEF components to live in and setting a variable in App.Config as well as the Build directory of the other projects to point there.  Thanks to @JaredPar for the help.

```
 var extensionFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExtensionPath"];
 var solutionPath = Directory.GetParent( System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ).Parent.FullName;
 var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
 catalog.Catalogs.Add( new DirectoryCatalog( solutionPath + extensionFolder ) );
 var container = new CompositionContainer( catalog );
 container.ComposeParts( this );
```

Answer (score 2):

MEF will only search the set of types / assemblies that is defined by the `CompositionContainer`.  In this case the assembly for `Type1` isn't in there hence it's never found.  In order or this to work you need to include the assembly for `Type1` in the `CompositionContainer` as well.

```
 catalog.Catalogs.Add( new AssemblyCatalog( typeof( Type1 ).Assembly )
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but wouldn't have I have to edit Program every time I add a new type?  I can use a directory but I'm not sure how to force types in a different project to compile to a certain directory:     
catalog.Catalogs.Add( new DirectoryCatalog( Path.GetDirectoryName( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location ) ) );

Comment: @Clarke most MEF base systems will just add all of the assemblies in a given directory so that it's configurable

Comment: @Clarke in my project i have a post-build step for each module project that copies the binaries to a 'modules' directory. `xcopy` is king!