# Static method of class A is not called from the static constructor of class B

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following classes

```
    public class A
    {

        protected static Dictionary<string,Func<BaseClass>> dict = new Dictionary<string,Func<BaseClass>>();

        public static void AddGenerator(string type,Func<BaseClass> fncCreateObject)
        {
            dict.Add(type,fncCreateObject);
        }

    }

    class B : BaseClass
    {
        static B()
        {
            A.AddGenerator("b",CreateObject);
        }

        protected B()
        {}

        pulic static B CreateObject()
        {
            return new B();
        }
    }
```

NOTE: The above code is simply an example but very closely relates to the what I'm trying to achieve.

Many people would advice using an IoC container such as NInject or Unity but my main reason for this post if to figure out why the above code does not execute as it is expected to.

So, in the above code, I'm expecting class B's static constructor to call on the static method of class A and an entry should be available in the dictionary for the rest of the application life cycle.

However, when I run the code and debug, I found that the dictionary is empty.

Why is the code invoked from class B's static constructor not executing?

Comment: You do at least call B.CreateObject() somewhere else in your code, right?

Comment: There's more to class A. It receive's a special collection containing the code and based on the code the generator function is invoked from the dictionary. It is during this process that I found that the dictionary is empty which means the code has not executed. So to answer your question, B.CreateObject would be invoked as dict["b"](); I have not included the rest of A's code.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but section [10.11 Static Constructors C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612(v=vs.71).aspx) says _The static constructor for a class executes at most once in a given application domain. The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain: An instance of the class is created., Any of the static members of the class are referenced._

Comment: I pasted it into a Console project (correcting the PULIC typo and made a dummy BaseClass) and it seems to stop in the correct places when I debug. I think you need to paste a more complete code sample (with some test code) that displays the issue.

Comment: Static connstructor B executes at first using class B. Are you sure you use class B as anything ?

Comment: I used the above code in an asp.net web application which I execute from an IIS 7.5 server

Comment: @IL_Agent : I'll have to check, but probably I'm not referencing class B anywhere before class A

Comment: Like @steve said ... You must reference it somehow at least once for the static constructor to kick in.

Comment: IS there any other way to kick in class B's static constructor without referencing class B ? My idea is to make class A so generic that if there are any new derived classes(deriving BaseClass) added to A, I should not need any modification or derivation to A and the new class should automatically fall in use

Comment: If I understand your need, you are trying to have a catalog of subtypes of BaseClass. That sounds a lot similar to Managed Extensibility Framework. Have you considered it?

Comment: This is never going to work - `B` is not even compiled before you try to do something with it. You want to try a different approach - Managed Extensibility Framework is certainly an option, or you could just manually use reflection to initialize all of your `BaseClass` derived classes and thus get them added to the generator list. In any case, `B`'s static constructor will not be executed until you explicitly use `B` *somewhere*. This is just how .NET's JIT and static constructors work.

Comment: @Derek : I need to make sure that there are no modifications to class A. Also the new subclasses of B could be added to the solution as time passes and new sub-types are requested/discovered. This is the first time I have heard of 'Managed Extensibility Framework'. I had a quick glance through the MSDN page but it would be helpful if you could provide me a very simple explanation as to how it will help achieve my goal

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

Clearly, at the point in your code where you inspect the dictionary, no instance has yet been created, and no static members have been referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a 1:1 translation, of your sample into MEF, but it should give you a good idea what MEF is capable of:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
    using System.Reflection;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");
            var compositeCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(assemblyCatalog, directoryCatalog);
            var container = new CompositionContainer(compositeCatalog);
            var a = A.Instance;
            container.SatisfyImportsOnce(a);
            a.PrintCatalog();
        }
    }

    public sealed class A
    {
        private static readonly A instance = new A();

        static A() { }

        private A() { }

        public static A Instance { get { return instance; } }

        [ImportMany]
        private List<IBType> BTypes;

        public void PrintCatalog()
        {
            foreach (var bType in BTypes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bType.GetType());
            }
        }

    }

    [Export(typeof(IBType))]
    class B:IBType
    {
        static B()
        {
        }

        protected B()
        {}

        public void DoSomething() {  }
    }

    [Export(typeof(IBType))]
    class B2:IBType
    {
        static B2()
        {
        }

        protected B2()
        {}

        public void DoSomething() {  }
    }

    interface IBType
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }

}
```

I've also included the safest implementation of a Singleton pattern known to me. MEF will allow you to source many implementations of the same interface which are resolved dynamically at runtime. I used it also with [**metadata attributes**](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2010/03/06/providing-metadata-to-you-mef-exports.aspx), like version and name. 
But if you need it to work with a base abstract class, check out [**this article**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313016/using-mef-with-abstract-base-class).

The same code as above, but with metadata attributes use sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");
            var compositeCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(assemblyCatalog, directoryCatalog);
            var container = new CompositionContainer(compositeCatalog);
            var a = A.Instance;
            container.SatisfyImportsOnce(a);
            a.PrintCatalog();
            a.BTypes.Single(s=>s.Metadata.Name.Equals("Second")).Value.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public sealed class A
    {
        private static readonly A instance = new A();

        static A() { }

        private A() { }

        public static A Instance { get { return instance; } }

        [ImportMany]
        public List<Lazy<IBType,IBTypeMetadata>> BTypes;

        public void PrintCatalog()
        {
            foreach (var bType in BTypes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bType.Value.GetType());
            }
        }

    }

    [Export(typeof(IBType))]
    [BTypeMetadata("First")]
    class B:IBType
    {
        static B()
        {
        }

        protected B()
        {}

        public void DoSomething() {  }
    }

    [Export(typeof(IBType))]
    [BTypeMetadata("Second")]
    class B2 : IBType
    {
        static B2()
        {
        }

        protected B2()
        {}

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from Second");
        }
    }

    public interface IBType
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }

    public interface IBTypeMetadata
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    [MetadataAttribute]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class BTypeMetadataAttribute : ExportAttribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public BTypeMetadataAttribute(string name)
            : base(typeof(IBTypeMetadata)) { Name = name; }
    }

}
```

IMHO, MEF might help you as long as your plan is to call some public methods from a particular instance of any of the B-types. In your sample, you simply create new instances of a B-type, and I think there is more to it than what your sample shows.

MEF will create catalogs for you from your currently loaded assembly, as well as any number of assemblies from any number of directories. You can even have it dynamically re-composable, meaning, at runtime, you could potentially retrieve a DLL from a server, and have it added to your catalog without shutting down the application.

MEF is also hierarchical, so your B-types can have their own "catalogs". And to wire it all up, all you have to do is to call SatifyImportsOnce passing an instance of class A.